# SSH to Ubuntu desktop

Tags: ssh

I've setup an SSH server on my Ubuntu desktop at home using a dynamic DNS service (NOIP). I have a wi-fi-only Android tablet running Android version 4.4.2. On my tablet I can connect to other SSH servers, such as my college's server. However, I cannot directly connect from my tablet to my desktop; every attempt times out. But I am able to connect to my college's server and then SSH into my desktop from there. Is there something I've not set up correctly in my sshd_config file possibly? I'm able to ping the public IP. But I'm at a loss to explain this behavior. I've used both JuiceSSH and ConnectBot to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: As per this -- *On my tablet I can connect to other SSH servers, such as my college's server. However, I cannot directly connect from my tablet to my desktop;* -- IMO, it should be migrated to [su] since I see no issue with Android itself.

Comment: You're right, Firelord. I figured out my issue and it wasn't Android related.

Comment: Can you post your solution and mark the question as answered?  Just so others can see the question is resolved and also what the solution to the problem was :)

Comment: Yeah absolutely. The problem was that my router does not support connecting to forwarded ports on the WAN IP from inside the LAN. This explains why I was able to connect to my WAN IP from my college's server but was unable to connect when using the WAN IP on my local network. 

Answers came from this [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622120/ssh-to-ubuntu-desktop?noredirect=1#comment880813_622120) post and this [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240514/connection-timeout-for-ssh-server) post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was that my router does not support connecting to forwarded ports on the WAN IP from inside the LAN. This explains why I was able to connect to my WAN IP from my college's server but was unable to connect when using the WAN IP on my local network.

Answers came from this [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622120/ssh-to-ubuntu-desktop?noredirect=1#comment880813_622120) post and this [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240514/connection-timeout-for-ssh-server) post.

edit: Unable to accept answer "until tomorrow."

Comment: Have you tried settings your noIP hostname as the router's hostname in your network settings?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have port forwarding or access list set on your router/firewall allowing only SSH from particular IP's?

This could explain why it works from a known location.

Comment: No, nothing is discriminating based on IPs.

Comment: I have a 7" tablet running 4.4.2 and installed JuiceSSH and connected to my Ubuntu 12.04lts successfully on the inside. 
Can you post your sshd_config file?

Comment: Were you able to connect using a domain name, or using your Ubuntu machine's local IP address? I was just told that it may not be possible to connect using the domain name while I'm on the same local network as my Ubuntu machine, so I may have to run out and find another wifi network to test that theory

Comment: Also, iptables I/F/O Chain Accept

Comment: I used inside IP address.

Comment: @onthelake Seeking information is done via comments and not via answer section (unless partial answer IMO). Please refrain from doing so.